# Printing in Java using PS file

Tags: java, printing, awt

I have a generated post script file and want to print using it. How can it be achieved in java either using javax print API or AWT. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Complicated.  Does your printer(s) support PostScript?  Is it networked?  If so, most networked printers can talk LPR and you can shove the file over as-is.  On Windows, you could also stream the file as-is to the `lpt1:` mapped port via something like `NET USE LPT1: \\[Computer Name]\Printer /PERSISTENT:YES`.

If you're on a server and you do lots of PostScript handling and your printer infrastructure supports it, I would very much look into the LPR protocol.  I've written several LPR/LPD management functions in Java to handle printer jobs, so definetely know it can be done with some relative ease.

http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc1179.pdf

Comment: Printer used: Canon iR5050 PCL6

Comment: Then you'll need to transform PS->PCL.  I'd write a web service to perform the same.

Comment: If i generate a PCL file instead of PS file so should i stream the PCL file to lpt1?

Comment: Yes, PCL should be able to be streamed/copied over to said port without issue (or at least every other PCL printer with which I've worked).  Ghostscript does a fantastic job of interpreting PostScript and transforming to other languages (e.g. PCL).  If this is a commercial venture, remember there are a LOT of advantages to PostScript in terms of document management, and a lot of advantages to LPD for print queuing vs. direct byte copying.

Comment: BTW, that printer should easily support PostScript, should not need to worry about PCL.

Comment: Oh is it. I was not sure if Canon iR5050 PCL6 can support PS. Be it PCL or PS docflavor, i am unable to get the printer instance using the doc flavor niether as PCL or PS using the code below. What could be the issue. DocFlavor psFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT; PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psFlavor, null);

Comment: Could you please share a sample java code to print using a PS script. I tried hard to get it but in vain.

Comment: Yep, http://www.canonir5050.com/ looks like `%!PS` magic is supported.  The code I'm discussing using LPR is not über-difficult, but nor is it trivial.  Contact me via my profile and I can share some additional info over email (it is commercial otherwise I'd post whatever snippets I could here).

Comment: With Canon iR5050 PCL6, I tried to use the basic print feature of javax print. I was able to print contents from a txt file but i am unable to modify the no. of copies, orientation etc. even when setting the PrintRequestAttributes. Is it a printer specific issue? Is there any way to get around it?

Comment: No. When i tried to fetch the supported docflavors of the printer using java print API, it does not specify PS or PCL.

Comment: I'm talking about sending via FTP protocol, not the print API.

Comment: If i FTP the PS to print the content, how do i specify the printer specific attributes like DUPLEX, LANDSCAPE etc.